# Symfony2 Profiler: save more entries

Tags: debugging, symfony, profiler

By default, the Symfony2 profiler only saves a few* of the last requests (Don't know how many excactly - something between 25 and 40). I think the list removes the older ones after a cupple of minutes..

I'd like to do a long-time profiling and measuring of some data. Is it possible to configure the max profiling amount? Or maybe store all the data in my (MongoDB) Database? (I'm currently using Symfony 2.2)

**Update**: I found out, that clearing the cache, also clears the profiler data - so I guess the key issue here is, to save the profiler data somewhere else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3806) out.

You can override the default `profiler.storage` service, which is defined [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/profiling.xml#L19).

You could either define your own class (implementing the [ProfilerStorageInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/ProfilerStorageInterface.php)) or use one of the provided implementations (check [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler) for the whole list).

For example if you want to use the [MongoDbProfilerStorage](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/MongoDbProfilerStorage.php) you can redefine the service as follows:

```
<service id="profiler.storage" class="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\MongoDbProfilerStorage" public="false">
    <argument>mongodb://[USER:PWD@]HOST/DATABASE/COLLECTION</argument>
    <argument></argument>
    <argument></argument>
    <argument>86400</argument>
</service>
```

This way you wouldn't delete profiler data whenever you clear the cache.

Comment: perfect solution! I like the idea. Should be documented in the cookbook, actually.. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it should. I literally had to dig into the code to find that out! You're welcome.